# Can't add Dictionary to Repl

Tags: elm

How can I add this to the repl with line returns?

```
import Dict
fruit = Dict.fromList \
    [ \
      ((0,0), 'Apple') \
      ,((0,1), ' ') \      
    ]
```

**Error**:

```
> fruit = Dict.fromList \
|     [ \
|       ((0,0), 'Apple') \
|       ,((0,1), ' ') \      
-- SYNTAX PROBLEM -------------------------------------------- repl-temp-000.elm

The = operator is reserved for defining variables. Maybe you want == instead? Or
maybe you are defining a variable, but there is whitespace before it?

5|   fruit = Dict.fromList
```

Is it just not possible to do this in the repl with lists where you want to add line returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a language I know but thought I'd take a look. This appears to work:

```
import Dict
fruit = Dict.fromList \
    [ \
      ((0,0), "Apple") \
      ,((0,1), " ") \
    ]
```

You seem to have some trailing whitespace after `,((0,1), ' ') \`

Also I needed double quotes which appears to be supported by https://elmprogramming.com/string.html

By way of minimal test - this behaves like your example if the trailing space is included:

```
import Dict
fruit = Dict.fromList [ \
```

Comment: hmm I noticed I can't have tabs either.  I do the syntax usually in Sublime and for some reason using tabs not spaces caused issues as well